# Convert Date in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, date

I have the following Dates in Excel:

```
> 20. Mrz 06
> 20. Mrz 07
> 20. Mrz 08
> 20. Mrz 09
> 20. Mrz 10
> 20. Mrz 11
> 20. Mrz 12
> 20. Mrz 13
> 20. Mrz 14
> 21. Mrz 06
> 21. Mrz 07
> 21. Mrz 08
> 21. Mrz 09
> 21. Mrz 10
> 21. Mrz 11
> 21. Mrz 12
> 21. Mrz 13
> 21. Mrz 14
> ...

and would like to convert it into the following:

> 20-03-06 
> 20-03-07 
> 20-03-08 
> 20-03-09 
> 20-03-10 
> 20-03-11 
> 20-03-12 
> 20-03-13 
> 20-03-14 
> 20-03-15
```

Unfotunatly it does not work in just converting the dates via excel number formating. Is there a way doing it in VBA?

Comment: How do you get from `21. Mrz 07` to `20-03-07`?

Comment: Ok, I got it, You have formatted it as a list and it auto incremented the values.

Comment: Do you have dates or strings?

Comment: @VincentG, I want more to convert the dates. I already have the list of dates but need to do it currently via replace to convert it. Is there a way doing it automatically to convert the list?

Comment: @FunThomas, I have it as Date (Excel shows it as custome date).

Comment: I suppose Mrz is a month abbreviation but I don't know the locale used.

Comment: If is is in the date format, youjust have to change the custom format to `dd-mm-yy`

Comment: `Custom date` is only the name of the formatting. That doesn't say anything about the value of your data. Can you add 1 to the date?

Comment: @VincentG, Yes Mrz is the month march and unfortunatly it does not work.

Comment: @FunThomas, No I cannot add a value of 1. I get #Value!

Comment: Then you have text strings, not dates. You first have to convert them to date values (which could be tricky because of the month names)

Comment: @FunThomas, do you have an example how I can do that and then how I can convert it to the dedicated date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have strings, not dates, and the strings doesn't follow any standard (containing month names, probably in German), you can try a UDF:

```
Function StrtoDate(s As String) As Date
    Dim MonthNames
    MonthNames = Array("Jan", "Feb", "Mrz", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez")

    Dim parts() As String
    parts = Split(s, " ")
    If UBound(parts) <> 2 Then Exit Function

    Dim d As Integer, m As Integer, y As Integer
    d = Val(parts(0))
    m = Application.Match(parts(1), MonthNames, False)
    y = Val(parts(2))
    If y < 100 Then y = y + 2000
    StrtoDate = DateSerial(y, m, d)
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. This is what Iw as looking for